# Save complexa data using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Hi every one I want to save complex data using `Entity Framework` and `C#`. I have 2 classes `Product` and `Order` defined as follows

**Product Class**

```
public class Product 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SKU_Code { get; set; }
        public string Product_Name { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created_Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified_Date { get; set; }
    }
```

**Order Class**

```
public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string Order_Id { get; set; }
        public string Payment_Type { get; set; }
        public string Customer_Name { get; set; }
        public string Shipping_Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime Order_Date { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified_Date { get; set; }
        public bool Flag { get; set; }
        public List<Product> ProductDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

And I want to save data Order details and my piece of code is as follows.

```
public Order Add(Order odrerDetails)
{
    using (var context = new EcommerceDBContext())
    {
        var MyOrder_Id = Helper.Random(7); //Generate random orderID from my class
        foreach (var detail in odrerDetails.ProductDetails)
        {
            odrerDetails.Order_Id = MyOrder_Id;                  
            odrerDetails.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(detail.Quantity);
            odrerDetails.Amount = Convert.ToDouble(detail.Price);

           //Other Details
            context.objOrderListing.Add(odrerDetails);
        }                
        context.SaveChanges();
        return odrerDetails;
    }
}
```

This gives me perfect data but when it comes to `context.SaveChanges();` it return's me error.

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types.

Comment: What is Add_Product?

Comment: Typo mistake it's only `Product`

Comment: Complex data, hehe :)

Comment: You don't have the foreign key attribute on your ProductDetails property on the Orders entity

Comment: @SabyasachiMishra I think you got the whole Add method wrong. I guess the idea is you have a list of products and you want to save the Order in the DB with multiple Products in the order? According to your code you are adding multiple orders.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar: Yes, want to save the Order in the DB with multiple Products in the order.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar: Actually, I want to save multiple orders with multiple Products of same OrderId in order table. No reflect in Product table.

Answer (score 0):

To me you domain model seems all wrong. The order should just be used for grouping, its a typical e-commerce scenario.

When you get a receipt of your purchases, you get one receipt with every Item and price listed next to it. Its considered as one order of multiple things, not multiple orders of multiple things.

Reading your last comment, you cant have multiple orders with the same order id. Try to understand the domain first before trying to solve it with code. Also,you have no notion of a Customer with an Order.

```
public class Product 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SKU_Code { get; set; }
    public string Product_Name { get; set; }        
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified_Date { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Order_Id { get; set; }
    public string Payment_Type { get; set; }
    public string Customer_Name { get; set; }
    public string Shipping_Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime Order_Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified_Date { get; set; }
    public bool Flag { get; set; }
    public List<OrderLineItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineItem
{
    [Key]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public long Order_Id { get; set; }
    public long Product_Id {get; set;}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
}
```